# How to batch send records to Azure Table Storage?

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I have 10,000 records I would like to upload to Azure table storage. Right now I am just passing them to the table table storage using a loop and sending the records one at a time.  Is there a way to batch upload records?

```
for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    task.PartitionKey = 'tableone'
    task.RowKey = row_key
    task.screenname = name
    task.text = text
    task.date = date
    task.coordinates = coords
    task.country = country
    task.city = city

table_service.insert_entity('testone', task)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use entity group transactions to send up to 100 entities at a time, as long as the have the same partition key https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx